# Search for tracks in Deezer playlist

Tags: deezer

In the Deezer API, is it possible to search for tracks in a specific playlist? Something like http://api.deezer.com/search/track?playlist=785141981&q=felix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can.

You will have to load the playlist with `http://api.deezer.com/playlist/785141981`, then look for the `tracks.data` property.

You will have all the tracks for this playlist then you can do the search  manually.